# Set database provider for Web Deploy

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, webdeploy

I am using VS 2017 on a project with .NET Core 2.0 and PostgreSql database. Npgsql is used as a db provider.

This is how DbContext is configured:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
          options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
             b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssembly")));

        ...
    }
```

This is the configuration of deployment
[image: Configuration]
When Web Deploy tries to apply migrations on publish process it gets an error:

> Error : Web deployment task failed.
>
> The value 'User ID=postgres;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MyDatabase' is not a valid connection string or an absolute path.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INVALID_CONNECTION_STRING.
>
> Keyword not supported: 'host'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ConnectionStringMatcher.RemoveExtraSlashFromDataSourceName(String connectionString)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ConnectionStringMatcher.GetStandardConnectionString(String userConnectionString, Boolean isSqlCE)
>      at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlInfo.GetBuilder(String connectionString, String errorMessageFormat)
>   Publish failed to deploy.

Seems like Web Deploy tries to parse connection string via default SqlServer database provider. How can I switch the database provider to Npgsql for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use 'User ID=postgres;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MyDatabase' as your connection string?

I think the problem is that you write 'User ID' which has a space in it, and you also don't include a password in the connection string.

Can you perhaps try this line instead, after you fill in the password?

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=MyDatabase;User=postgres;Password=YourPassword"
```

Comment: 'User Id...' It is the syntax of PosgreSql connection string. It is valid and working on local machine.